# Python -- Procurar no arquivo TXT

Tags: python

Tenho um arquivo em Python para registro de alunos.Gostaria de criar um outro programa, para que eu escreva o nome do aluno e o programa já informe os dados do aluno que estão anotados no arquivo.

**Código:**

```
import os

cadastrar_aluno = 's'
nome_arquivo = "alunos.txt"
nome_escola = "ESCOLA MUNICIPAL FULANO DA SILVA"
separador = "-" * len(nome_escola)
cabecalho =  separador + "\n" + nome_escola + "\n" + separador

if not os.path.exists(nome_arquivo):
    arquivo_cadastro = open(nome_arquivo, 'w+t', encoding="utf-8")
    arquivo_cadastro.write(cabecalho)
    arquivo_cadastro.close()
    
def salvar_aluno(aluno):
    arquivo_cadastro = open(nome_arquivo, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    posicao_aluno = arquivo_cadastro.read().count("Aluno") + 1
    arquivo_cadastro.close()
    
    arquivo_cadastro = open(nome_arquivo, 'a+t', encoding="utf-8")
    arquivo_cadastro.write("\nAluno " + str(posicao_aluno) + "\n")
    
    for chave in aluno:
        arquivo_cadastro.write("- " + chave + ": " + aluno[chave] + "\n")
    
    arquivo_cadastro.write(separador)
    arquivo_cadastro.close()

while cadastrar_aluno == 's':
    #cadastro do aluno
    aluno = {
      "Nome": "",
      "CPF": "",
      "Mãe": "",
      "Data de Nascimento": "",
      "Idade": 0,
      "Série": ""
    }
    
    aluno["Nome"] = input("Digite o nome do aluno:")
    aluno["CPF"] = input("Digite o CPF do aluno:")
    aluno["Mãe"] = input("Digite o nome da mãe do aluno:")
    aluno["Data de Nascimento"] = input("Digite a data de nascimento do aluno:")
    aluno["Idade"] = input("Digite a idade do aluno:")
    aluno["Série"] = input("Digite a série do aluno:")
    
    '''    
    print("Digite os campos abaixo para cadastrar um aluno:")
    for chave in aluno:
        aluno[chave] = input(chave + ":")
    '''

    salvar_aluno(aluno)
    
    cadastrar_aluno = input("Deseja cadastrar mais um aluno? (s ou n)").lower()

#comando_abrir_arquivo = "notepad " + nome_arquivo
#os.system(comando_abrir_arquivo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos usar um argumento para o nome do aluno, abrir o ficheiro, dividir pelo separador, realizar um ciclo pelos alunos e comparar o argumento com a 2ª linha que contém o nome do aluno.

```
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) >= 2):
    nome = sys.argv[1]
    encontrou_resultados = False
    with open("alunos.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
        texto = f.read()
        dados = texto.split("--------------------------------")

        for i in range(2, len(dados) - 1):
            aluno = dados[i].strip()
            linhas = aluno.splitlines()
            if nome.strip().lower() == linhas[1][8:].strip().lower():
                encontrou_resultados = True
                print(aluno)

        if encontrou_resultados == False:
            print("Não existem resultados.")
else:
    print("Argumentos inválidos.")
```